# Super Keys cannot be remapped using xmodmap

Tags: node.js, linux, keyboard, xmodmap

I'm developing an application with a kiosk to it. It's an examination delivery platform, and I'm developing the Linux version through electron.js. I'm looking to kiosk the application by forcing a fullscreen mode and using an xmodmap binary to prevent the use of modifier keys (Ctrl, Alt, Fn 1-12, Super, Hyper). I built a keymap file to lock and revert the mechanism accordingly, but unfortunately the Super key does not remap. Output for when I run `xev -event keyboard` and press the Super key below.

```
KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    root 0x799, subw 0x6400002, time 1760838, (45,47), root:(45,104),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Accordingly, I created a revert keymap and a locking keymap to disable/enable the keys.

```
! revert keymap
! encoding=utf-8

keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R
keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
keycode 205 = NoSymbol Meta_L NoSymbol Meta_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 207 = NoSymbol Hyper_L NoSymbol Hyper_L
keycode  67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
keycode  68 = F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 XF86Switch_VT_2
keycode  69 = F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 XF86Switch_VT_3
keycode  70 = F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4
keycode  71 = F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5
keycode  72 = F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 XF86Switch_VT_6
keycode  73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7
keycode  74 = F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 XF86Switch_VT_8
keycode  75 = F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 XF86Switch_VT_9
keycode  76 = F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10
keycode  95 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
keycode  96 = F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12
```

```
! lockfile keymap
! encoding=utf-8

keycode  37 = 
keycode 105 = 
keycode 133 = 
keycode  64 = 
keycode 108 = 
keycode 204 = 
keycode 205 = 
keycode 134 = 
keycode 206 = 
keycode 207 = 
keycode  67 = 
keycode  68 = 
keycode  69 = 
keycode  70 = 
keycode  71 = 
keycode  72 = 
keycode  73 = 
keycode  74 = 
keycode  75 = 
keycode  76 = 
keycode  95 = 
keycode  96 =
```

Every other key is disabled perfectly, why does super key remain enabled? How can I circumvent this?
Device Specifications -> 5.10.12-arch1-1 KWin Plasma 5.20.5 (x86_64)

Comment: run `xmodmap` in terminal to get modifiers and then `remove mod4 = Super_L` or whatever `mod` it is and see if this helps

Comment: I tried this, `mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)` became `mod4              `, unfortunately there was no difference in how it ran.